# How to check if jQuery object exist in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Given an `item` and an `array`, I would like to know if `item` exist in `array`.

`item` is a jQuery object, e.g. `$(".c")`. You can assume that `item.length == 1`.

`array` is an array of jQuery objects, e.g. `[$(".a"), $(".b")]`. Each item in this array may represent 0, 1, or more objects.

Here is how I thought to implement this: ([live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/e3WwB/1/))

```
function inArray(item, arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var items = $.makeArray(arr[i]);

        for (var k = 0; k < items.length; k++) {
            if (items[k] == item[0]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Can you find a more elegant implementation?

---

**Example:**

HTML:

```
<div class="a">Hello</div>
<div class="a">Stack</div>
<div class="a">Overflow</div>

<div class="b">Have</div>
<div class="b">a</div>
<div class="b">nice</div>
<div class="b">day!</div>

<div class="c">Bye bye</div>
```

JS:

```
console.log(inArray($(".a").eq(2), [$(".a"), $(".b")])); // true
console.log(inArray($(".b").eq(3), [$(".a"), $(".b")])); // true
console.log(inArray($(".c"), [$(".a"), $(".b")]));       // false
console.log(inArray($(".a").eq(2), [$(".b")]));          // false
console.log(inArray($(".a").eq(2), []));                 // false
console.log(inArray($(".c"), [$("div")]));               // true
```

Comment: Does it have to be an array? Why don't you use a jQuery object and [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)?

Comment: @Felix: I guess you mean to use `$(".a, .b")`. Sounds reasonable!

Comment: Or you can use [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to build up the jQuery object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Felix's suggestion:

`[$(selector1), $(selector2), ... ]` can be simplified to

```
$(selector1, selector2, ...)
```

or

```
$(selector1).add(selector2)...
```

and then it can be implemented as:

```
function inArray(item, arr) {
  return (arr.index(item) != -1);
}
```

[Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/e3WwB/3/)

Comment: Good solution! I don't think this really needs a function wrapper, though - while the OP was in its own function, just doing the one line inside the function here is more than enough.

Answer (score 8):

what about

```
if(jQuery.inArray(some, array) === -1)
{
//process data if "some" is not in array
}
else
{
//process if "some" is in array
}
```

read here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: Although upvoted many times, this is NOT working for an array that contains jQuery objects (which is what the OP asked for). See Misha's own answer for a correct solution, using jQuery's .index() method.

Comment: This solution does not work for array of jquery elements

Answer (score 0):

```
if($.inArray("valueYouWantToFind", nameOfTheArray) == true) {
  Your code;
 }

 Eg.,
 var userChoice = ["yes"];
 if($.inArray('yes',userChoice) == true) {
                    alert("found");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(!!~$.inArray("a", ["a", "b", "c"]));
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a little?  "Try this" style answers don't explain much and encourages the same questions to get asked over and over.

Comment: Agreeing with the comment above: elaborating on why this is an answer would help everyone, especially where you're using two of JavaScript's "tricks" in one line.

Answer (score -1):

```
data = [
  {val:'xxx',txt:'yyy'},
  {val:'yyy',txt:'aaa'},
  {val:'bbb',txt:'ccc'}
];

            var dummyArray = [];
            var distinctValueArray = [];

            $.each(data, function (index, firstobject) {
              //push first element of object in both dummy array and distinct array.

               if (index == 0) {
                    distinctValueArray.push(firstobject);
                    dummyArray.push(firstobject.txt);
                }
                else {

                    //started from 2nd index.

                   if ($.inArray(firstobject.txt, dummyArray) == -1) {
                        distinctValueArray.push(firstobject);
                    }
                    dummyArray.push(firstobject.txt);
                }
            });
            dummyArray.length=0;
```