# jquery inArray()

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if jQuery object exist in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769022/how-to-check-if-jquery-object-exist-in-array)

is there any way to determine if a dom element is in an array of dom elements?

i.e.

```
$(".container img").each(function(){
   views.push($(this).clone());
});
```

creates an array of cloned image elements. I now want to check if a new image element is in that array?

Thanks

Comment: `views.indexOf( yourImage ) !== -1`

Comment: You don't like [`inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)? You already wrote it in the title...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".container img").each(function(){
    if(jQuery.inArray($(this), views) === -1)
    {
        views.push($(this).clone());
    }
});
```

or check [How to check if jQuery object exist in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769022/how-to-check-if-jquery-object-exist-in-array) for other solutions.

For your use check out http://jsfiddle.net/hxAg4/34

Comment: @Christoph sorry, my copy from textwrangler didn't work properly. Fixed.

Comment: can you tell me why this isn't working then please?

http://jsfiddle.net/hxAg4/18/

Comment: @Seglespaan can you create an http://jsfiddle.net with your code and html?

Comment: ahh, you edited the comment. Give me a minute, jsfiddle seems to be down right now.

Comment: @Seglespaan I cannot run the code but I can see it. jsfiddle is still not working properly. However, you have `$('.container')` but only have `id="container"`. `.` is for a `class` while `#` is for `id`

Comment: Uber fail, not just in my fiddle, but i noticed two of the data attributes in my new image were the wrong way around which was causing the problem.

Comment: @Seglespaan http://jsbin.com/ibuvej/1/edit also in the jsfiddle you had `$(image)` instead of just `image`

Comment: I thought inArray retunr -1 if id couldn't find the element in the array?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18927/discussion-between-bot-and-seglespaan)